# Receiving a value error when using OneHotEncoder and fitting data

Tags: python, sklearn-pandas

I'm working on an assignment and we are using OneHotEncoder in scikit-learn to make all categories print out. Here is the a sample of the data and the code I used to transform it:

```
      grade sub_grade  short_emp  emp_length_num home_ownership        term
0          B        B2          0              11           RENT   36 months
1          C        C4          1               1           RENT   60 months
2          C        C5          0              11           RENT   36 months
3          C        C1          0              11           RENT   36 months
4          A        A4          0               4           RENT   36 months
5          E        E1          0              10           RENT   36 months
```

Code:

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import OneHotEncoder
encoder = OneHotEncoder(categorical_features='all', handle_unknown='error', n_values='auto', sparse=True)
encoder.fit(lending_club)
```

The error I'm receiving is on the term column:

```
ValueError: could not convert string to float: ' 36 months'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`OneHotEncoder` does not support string features. You have to convert them to integers before, using `LabelEncoder` for example. Another option would be to use `LabelBinarizer` on all columns.

See [How to do Onehotencoding in Sklearn Pipeline](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42204250/how-to-do-onehotencoding-in-sklearn-pipeline/42220530).

Comment: Another question, I'm getting value error on trying to pass the DataFrame with a selection of more than one string column such as lending_club['grade', 'term']. Should I split the the DataFrame into two Frames? Or use the DataMapper so split the string data from the numeric data?

Comment: Can you create a new question in SO with all the info needed, please?

Answer (score 0):

scikit-learn's `OneHotEncoder` supports string from 0.20.0.