# One-Hot-Encoding deleting 3 values in my columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, encoding, one-hot-encoding

```py
from sklearn.preprocessing import OneHotEncoder
column_to_encode = ['Sex','Fasting_Blood_Sugar','Exercise_Angina']

# Create a nominal encoder object
encoder = OneHotEncoder(drop="first")

# Fit and transform the specified column using the encoder
encoded_column = encoder.fit_transform(df[column_to_encode])

# Convert the encoded column to a DataFrame
encoded_df = pd.DataFrame(encoded_column.toarray(), columns=encoder.get_feature_names_out(column_to_encode))

# Concatenate the encoded DataFrame with the original DataFrame
df = pd.concat([df, encoded_df], axis=1)

# Drop the original column that was encoded
df.drop(column_to_encode, axis=1, inplace=True)
```

I am trying this code. And three values from the dataset are deleted. Please help me understand this
[image: pandas' output]

Comment: Could you provide a minimal reproducible example? We do not have access to the data (df). If we have some example data (a few lines, not the whole dataset), we can yank the whole code in our interpreters and find the issue immediately. People will love helping you if you do that.

Answer (score 0):

You should utilize the [get_dummies()](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.get_dummies.html) function instead. This is the function you are supposed to use when encoding things on the fly. I would recommend using OneHotEncoder only when working with pipelines, where it will work on its own.

```py
import pandas as pd

data = dict(
    sex=['male','male','male','female','female','female'],
    name=['john', 'jack', 'joe', 'jeane', 'julia', 'jasmin'])
    
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

pd.get_dummies(df.sex)
```

[image: output of pd.get_dummies(df.sex)]

```py
pd.concat([df, pd.get_dummies(df.sex)], axis=1)
```

[image: output of pd.concat([df, pd.get_dummies(df.sex)], axis=1)]

Comment: actually im practicing pipelines so this is my homework to use sklearn oterwise i use getdummies

Comment: I got what you need, Tell me if it solved the problem: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42204250/how-to-do-onehotencoding-in-sklearn-pipeline

Comment: Don't hesitate to check the official documentation and try their codes first: https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.pipeline.Pipeline.html AND https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.OneHotEncoder.html Also, verify your version of scikit-learn `sklearn.__version__`, I've had issues with Tensorflow compatibility on new installs yesterday. Make your you re using a version >1.2.2 and not a 0.2 or something. ;)